# Android admob permissions

Tags: android, permissions, admob

my android app already has the following permission:

android.permission.INTERNET"

I want to use the admob ads in ma application. I have seen a lot of examples how to use the admob in android and always

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

was needed as well.

Does anyone know if admob will work without the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission, since this would require me to add another permission to the manifest.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This permission basically allows admob to check if you're conneted to the internet or not

without it it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how the [manual](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/android-legacy/docs/#android-permissions) literally states

> Making ad requests requires the networking permissions INTERNET and
>   ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, so these must also be declared in the manifest

I'd suggest it *really* requires the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission. They are not just saying that to annoy their developers.